# HTML - Keeping content above bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I just created a large table within a div structured page. The table is larger than the initial page, which causes the scroll bar to appear which is absolutely fine. However when you scroll to the bottom of the page, the last row is flush with the bottom of the page. This doesn't seem visually appealing to me. Previously I have solved this by adding one last row to the table, and adjusting the height and transparency. Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a more proper way to accomplish this using wrapping divs?

Thanks!

Comment: Create fiddle and add your code.

Comment: It should be possible by adding padding from bottom, which will result in some extra space. Also you can add some extra container (sort of footer or section splitter) after the one which holds your table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to answer without the code but a very simple solution would be adding a padding-bottom  to the body.

```
<body style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
```

Comment: Seconded. Other options depending on the design are to add padding to the div that contains the table, or a margin on the bottom of the table.